# Question about Lemma 4.7 in AKS paper

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, algorithms

I am reading this [version](https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf/) of the AKS paper.

I can't figure out, why is $\mathcal{G}$ that appears in Hednrik Lenstra's lemma 4.7 a group. It's obviously closed under multiplication, but I can't understand, why is it closed for inverses and why are all elements non-zero.

Thank you for helping in advance!

Comment: It is finite, so if elements are invertible in a latrger set they are finite powers.

Comment: @ahulpke I have just edited my question. In order to use you comment, I first have to prove that all elements of $\mathcal{G}$ are non-zero. I can't figure out how to do that either.

Comment: @ahulpke Figured it out. Because the degree of $h(X)$ is bigger than one, none of the polynomials $X, X + 1, \ldots, x + l$ is zero, and because we are working in a field, their product won't be zero either, so none of the elements of $\mathcal{G}$ are zero. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Now I have figured out that my proof is not correct. It is like saying that 5 can't divide 3 in $\mathbb{Z}_7$.

Comment: Granville is easier to read  https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2005-42-01/S0273-0979-04-01037-7/

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you. However, I don't understand Granville's proof completely either. In his proof that all the elements of $\mathcal{G}$ (Granville uses the letter $G$) are non-zero (the proof is by contradiction), he makes an implication that $n \equiv 1\; (\bmod\; r)$. When he makes that implication, he uses the fact that in $\mathbb{F}$ the order of $X$ is $r$ i. e. $X$ is an $r$-th primitive root of unity in $\mathbb{F}$, but he doesn't prove this anywhere. It is obvious to me that $X$ is an $r$-th root of unity but I can't figure out why it is a primitive root.

Comment: I finally found a definition for $h(X).$  Do you have the Lidl and Niedeerreiter book, Introduction to Finite Fields?

Comment: top of page 18,   Granville says $G$   is cyclic. That is a promising idea for showing it is a group, not just semigroup. I see, same paragraph you mention, with $n=1 \pmod r$  which contradicts some hypothesis somewhere. Well, off to get groceries.

Comment: @WillJagy I do have the book Introduction to Finite Fields. I don't, however, understand in what way do you think that the comment that $G$ is cyclic would be helpful. The only part that I don't understand in the proof that $G$ is a multiplicative subgroup, is the part that proves that $G$ contains only non-zero elements.